# latex editor with nice full screen no distraction appearance?

Tags: editors

Some markdown-based text editors have really nice and clean full screen appearance, e.g. Ulysses, Typora, etc. I mean, the full screen mode has adequate margins, no distraction, like a typewriter experience.

But some of my writings are better done with LaTeX, and I usually use Texstudio and Texshop. But it seems that LaTeX editors do not have nice and clean full screen mode as those markdown editors. The full screen mode of LaTeX editors is usually just an enlarged window with normal format.

This makes me think if there is a LaTeX editor that has nice and clean `typewriter` looking when I full screen it. Suggestions?

Here is the full screen on Ulysses:

[image]

And this is the full screen on Typora:

[image]

But TexShop is like this:

[image]

I am thinking if there is a LaTeX editor that has the editing environment like the first two.

Comment: What macOS version are you using? Recent macOS versions allow TeXShop to go into full screen mode. Even the Menubar gets out of the way.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the most recent version I guess. Sierra. TexShop does give me a full screen mode but it just enlarges the text to the full screen, which does not leave enough margins. But maybe I've asked for too much.

Comment: Emacs can be used in full screen mode and many users remove all toolbars. You can't have less distractions than this.

Comment: In TeXShop (current version 3.75), if you open a source window and then make it full-screen, the text font size remains the same (as set in Preferences > Source).

Comment: What features of a TeX editor do you want in full-screen mode?

Comment: I suggest your favorite terminal text editor (like Vim or Emacs) in a purged terminal window (without any borders, title, icons, etc.) on an *empty* desktop the background of which is *the same color as* the background of the terminal where your text editor is running. You set whatever you think are appropriate margins simply by resizing the window, choose whatever color you want, any typeface you like, etc. (What is unclear is how to achieve double spacing in a terminal.)

Comment: Following up on what @giordano suggested, I can highly recommend [`writeroom-mode`](https://github.com/joostkremers/writeroom-mode) for emacs. Before switching to emacs, I had been using SublimeText in [Distraction Free Mode](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/distraction_free.html) for quite some time.

Comment: MacVim does this fairly nicely in full screen mode.  To get a left margin use `set foldcolumn=20` (or whatever width you prefer).  You then probably want to do `set nonumber` to get rid of the line numbers, and you might want to play with `hi FoldColumn guibg=white` or some other nice relaxing shade.

Comment: Let's cut to the chase: The underlying problem is that the TeX editor needs a margin. I can say the same for TeXworks. This is a simple UI factor, not a cause for changing the workflow

Answer (score 1):

While TeXstudio does not provide an explicit distraction-free mode, it's configurability allows to hide almost all GUI elements. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364955/24770) for details:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to use a general proposed text editor. I use Visual Studio Code with some extension. Atom is also a good option but with poor performance. You can tweak almost everything. [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which extension do you use? Can you please explain better?

Comment: In visual studio code i use LaTeX Workshop, you can set up your project root folder and the compilation
 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop

Also, you can use an extension to see pdf inside of the window and use the integrated terminal to compile (using pdflatex), to me this way is faster but sometimes is more difficult.

And the most important :D, there are a lot of syntax themes and you can set up the look of the editor as you want.