# Distraction-free writing with TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

Is it possible to configure TeXstudio for distraction free writing?

Comment: What do you mean with distraction-free? fullscreen and without menus?

Answer (score 7):

While there is no explicit distraction-free mode in TeXstudio, it's configurability allows to hide almost all GUI elements.

First, you can use the fullscreen mode (F11 or double-click on an empty part of the menu bar).

Then hide unwanted elements:

- `View -> Show`
- Context menu on menu or toolbars to show/hide toolbars
- `Options -> Internal PDF Viewer -> Auto-hide toolbars in Embedded Mode`
- `Options -> Advanced Editor -> Appearance ->` + `Show Line Change State | Show State Panel | Show Line Numbers`

  Note: the toolbar settings are saved separately for normal and fullscreen mode. All other settings are global.

[image]